# Removing nth row in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, resampling

I have a Pandas df with a time series that goes by 34 milliseconds and I only need a 5 second resolution. I initially created a time stamp and tried to both setting the time stamp as an index and resample and .iloc.

```
# Defining file path
file = "C:/file/path/data.csv"

# Read in data and parse date/time to DateTime format
data = pd.read_csv(file,header=10,parse_dates=[[0,1]],dayfirst=False)

# time stamp in preferred format
data['date_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date_ Time'],dayfirst=False)

#trying to get every 5 seconds, not 34 milliseconds
data.iloc[::15,:]

# saving new file to csv
data.to_csv(""C:/file/path/data.csv"",date_format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Would this be best to do a time index and resample? This code always returns the same data in the df. Whats the best way to condense this data into 5 second intervals?

Comment: what is wrong with `resample()`?

Comment: depends on what you want, IMO `resampl`ing is what I'd do

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate every 5 seconds (sum/avg/etc the rows) or just grab all the rows that are 5 seconds apart from each other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.first.html):

```
data.set_index('date_stamp', inplace=True)
print (data.resample('5S').first())
```

See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#resample-api)

If use older pandas as `0.18.0`:

```
print (data.resample('5S', how='first'))
```